# choosing ctor arguments at runtime

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

Is it possible to address the following scenario of choosing the argument at runtime with mpl?

```
struct A {
    A(int number) { /* use number */ } };
struct B { };

template <typename T, int n>
struct A_or_B_Holder {
    A_or_B_Holder() : _t( /* void or 'n', depends on T */ ) { }
private:
    T _t;
};

A_or_B_Holder<B, void> b;
A_or_B_Holder<A, 3> a;
```

Ideally,

```
A_or_B_Holder<B> b;
A_or_B_Holder<A, 3> a;
```

Comment: Sounds like a Boost variant...

Comment: Is creating specializations for A_or_B_Holder out of the question?

Comment: Specializations are out of the question - I'd have to create many specializations for each private member of types T, T_1, T_2, ... etc. What I'd like is to instruct the template that in one case I want the T member to be created with a 'void' argument and in another with '3'.

Comment: @Bob: So what you are really asking about is a `A_or_B_or_C_or..._Holder<A, 3, B, void, C, 2, D, 10, E, void, ...>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that `void` is a type, not an integer. You could make the template accept two types, the second being either `boost::mpl::int_` or `void`.

Then you could either specialize the entire struct, or you could put the data member in a base class and specialize that.

```
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>

struct A {
    A(int number) { /* use number */ } };
struct B { };

template <class T, class Value>
struct A_or_B_Holder_Base{
    A_or_B_Holder_Base(): _t(Value::value) {}
protected:
    T _t;
};

template <class T>    
struct A_or_B_Holder_Base<T, void> {
    A_or_B_Holder_Base(): _t() {}
protected:
    T _t;
};

template <typename T, typename Value>
struct A_or_B_Holder : public A_or_B_Holder_Base<T, Value> {

};

using boost::mpl::int_;
A_or_B_Holder<A, int_<3> > x;
A_or_B_Holder<B, void> y;
A_or_B_Holder<A, void > w;  //error, no default constructor
A_or_B_Holder<B, int_<3> > z;  //error, no int constructor
```

More natural might be not to require the parameter to be a compile-time constant (as you are turning the compile-time constant into a run-time variable anyway). Just overload the constructor.

```
struct A {
    A(int number) { /* use number */ } };
struct B { };


template <typename T>
struct A_or_B_Holder {
    A_or_B_Holder() : _t( ) { }
    A_or_B_Holder(int number): _t(number) {}
private:
    T _t;
};

A_or_B_Holder<B> b;
A_or_B_Holder<A> a(3);
```

Comment: You should also add a `template<int val> struct Value {enum {value=val};};` and some sample usage code.

Comment: Also, a warning that T types must be copy-constructable.

Comment: @Mooing: From all I can see, A and B **are** copy-constructible. But as to the edit, the whole attempt with compile-time constant arguments where they are **not required** seems flawed.

Comment: The problem is that a(3) is not viable if A_or_B_Holder must be used via its default constructor. In my case, a third party library which expects a type, specified at compile time, constructs it with its default ctor, then manipulating it and returning it back to me.

Comment: @Bob: Honestly, it really sounds like A_Holder and B_Holder should be separate types.

Comment: @Bob - what does the library do with the object? if it needs to manipulate it (templated library functions?) wouldn't you want to avoid using a container as your type?

Comment: @Mooing: Edited so as not to require copy constructor.

Comment: +1 for code that looks just like mine, but not using a magic constant.

Answer (score 0):

I think that passing different arguments *at run time* is impossible.  You'll have to have a standard constructor that all T types will have.  You can make all T types construct from `std::vector<void*>` and use that to pass a variable number of variable type arguments, but that's **super** dangerous.

However, your sample seems to actually be deciding at compile-time, not run-time, which is solvable.

```
const int NO_INT_PARAM=INT_MIN;
template <typename T, int n>
struct A_or_B_Base {
    A_or_B_Holder() : _t(n) { }
private:
    T _t;
};
template <typename T>
struct A_or_B_Base<T, NO_INT_PARAM> {
    A_or_B_Holder() : _t() { }
private:
    T _t;
};
template <typename T, int n=NO_INT_PARAM>
struct A_or_B_Holder : A_or_B_Base<T, n>{
    A_or_B_Holder() : A_or_B_Base() { }
    /* other functions*/
};

A_or_B_Holder<A, 3> a; //uses A(3) constructor
A_or_B_Holder<B> b;  //uses B() constructor
A_or_B_Holder<A> c; //compiler error! A() doesn't exist!
A_or_B_Holder<B, 5> d;  //compiler error! B(5) doesn't exist!
A_or_B_Holder<B, NO_INT_PARAM> e;  //same as b, uses B() constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Boost.Variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html)

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct A
{
};

struct B
{
    B(int)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    boost::variant<A, B> val;

    if (/*some condition*/)
    {
        val = A();
    }
    else
    {
        val = B(5);
    }
}
```

If you are more interested in how this is implemented, rather than what you can use, I suggest you check out the implementations of [`Boost.Any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/any.hpp) and [`Boost.Variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/variant.hpp).

Comment: Judging by Bob's comment to UncleBen's answer after you posted this, some of those member functions might be required.